# JavaScript disable button based on php session value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Ok so i scrapped my previous attempt and now am trying to disable the relevant button depending on the value of current pos and the length of the queue. Is this better? can anyone see where i am going wrong and how i should fix it so that the buttons actually be disabled depending on the right value?

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['currentpos'] < sizeof($_SESSION['queue'])){           
   $_SESSION['currentpos']++;
   print("You have watched " . $_SESSION['currentpos'] . " out of " . count($_SESSION['queue']) . " clips.");
   $temp = $_SESSION['currentpos'];
   $query = "SELECT * FROM video WHERE video_id = :videoid";
   try { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':videoid', $_SESSION['queue'][$temp]['video_id']);
        $result = $stmt->execute();         
   } 
   catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
   if ($result) {
       while( $row = $stmt->fetchObject() ) {
            $_SESSION['videourl'] = $row->url;
        }
    }
    unset($_SESSION['sessionid']);              
?>

<div id="next">
        <p> Thank you for completing the forms, please click the button below to begin the next clip</p>        
        <a class="btn btn-danger" id="nextbt" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['currentpos']; ?>" href="newviewvideo.php?url=<?php echo $_SESSION['videourl']; ?>" role="button">Start Next Video</a>

        <a class="btn btn-danger" id="endbt" value="<?php sizeof($_SESSION['queue']); ?>" href="loginhomenew.php" role="button">Login Home</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($('#nextbt').val() === $('#endbt').val()) {
{
    $('#nextbt').prop('disabled', true); 
    $('#endbt').prop("disabled", false);
}
else
{
    $('#endbt').prop("disabled", false);
}
});
```

Comment: In addition to Misunderstood's comment, bear in mind that PHP is a server-side and Javascript is client-side.  PHP can't perform javascript, period.  Generally speaking, that's where AJAX comes into the picture when javascript is able to perform XMLHttpRequest behind the screen; or have PHP to parse the data in JSON.  jQuery / AJAX / Javascript would be good combination.

Comment: @Faron AJAX is not the way to do this.  The OP is just using JS to hide the div.  When the PHP is done correctly the unneeded div will not be output to the Browser.

Comment: You lost your "end" div.

Comment: yes ive now for the sake of trying to get something working decided to put the two buttons in the one div and set the second button to be disabled initially. however id like it to be changed from disabled when the the two values of the buttons are the same and set the other button to be disabled instead. Do you think this is achievable?

Comment: Look at my code, you will see it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

## Update

**CSS**

```
#nextbt,#endbt{display:none;}
```

**PHP**

```
if($type == 1){$bt = 'nextbt';}else{$bt = 'endbt';}
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('<?php$bt?>').display='block';";
```

**end of update**

---

Just do your SQL and define a variable that says whether to show the End or Next div.

$type 1 = Next

```
<?php
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=60');
header('Vary: Accept-Encoding');
echo <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<style>
</style>
</head><body><div id="page">
EOT;
ob_flush();
```

The `ob_start` is used to get the output on it's way to the Browser while you do the SQL.  The server will start sending the HTML to the Browser on the `ob_flush()`

Otherwise nothing will be transmitted until the end of the script.

The majority of the HTTP is prior to "First Byte"

To improve "Time to First Byte" (TFFB), you flush after the `<head>` and right before you need PHP to create the next HTML to be output.

Do not link to CSS.  Just put the CSS in the `<head><style>`, this will also help a lot in getting getting the Browser to "First Paint".

```
-----  SQL  ------

  if($type == 1){
    $js = "\ndocument.getElementById('next').style.display='hide';";
  }
  else{
    $js = "\ndocument.getElementById('end').style.display='hide';";
  }

  $currentpos = $_SESSION['currentpos'];
  $videourl = $_SESSION['videourl'];
  $cnt = count($_SESSION['queue']); 
  echo <<<EOT
<div id="next">
 <p> Thank you for completing the forms, please click the button below to begin the next clip</p>        
 <a class="btn btn-danger" id="nextbt" value="$currentpos" href="newviewvideo.php?url="$videourl" role="button">Start Next Video</a>

</div>
<div id="end">
<p> Thank you for completing the forms, please click the button below to end</p>
<a class="btn btn-danger" id="endbt" value="$cnt" href="loginhomenew.php" role="button">Login Home</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
 $js
//]]>
</script></body></html>
EOT;
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: I know its awfully coded, dissertation due in a day and its got to the point where im stressed out and just need something that works man so apologies. Im unfamiliar with the EOT syntax youve used so dont even know how to build on your answer to get a working file.

Comment: Calm down.  I will help.  It's call Heredoc syntax. I am here, I will get this done ASAP.  As fast as you can respond, I will too. Just create a new script and copy my code into it.  Let me know what happens.

Comment: Thanks, i will edit my question to try and be more specific about what i am trying to do and what each of my session variables contain.

Comment: Misunderstood thank you ever so much for trying to help me and for taking the time to write such a detailed example but as i said earlier this is for my dissertation project and im afraid that thsi code is just so different from my other code and if i used your example i wouldnt be able to talk about it and what it does sufficiently in my report.

Comment: Oh, OK, I can still help.  What is the topic?

Comment: How's that?  Is that what you are looking for?  What is the topic, I can probably get you an A++ with some stuff I have done where I create JS in PHP.

Comment: Again sorry because its using the EOT i wouldnt be able to include it without triggering some questions from my supervisor that i wouldnt be able to answer. Basically i am just looking for a way to dictate the flow of my site based on if they have finished the queue or not (by checking if the current pos is less than the queue size) but didnt get it working. Thanks for your effort though, it gets an A++ from me!

Comment: no i didnt get it to work but i have given up and just kept the two buttons on my page at all times now. Im sorry i cant upvote as i dont have enough reputation but if i don't receive another answer before my deadline tomorrow i will accept your answer

Comment: So what do you need to get working now?  What precisely is not working with your current post?  I'll get working.  Not a problem.  This stuff is very easy for me.  If you want I'll help you.  A faster response time, on your part,and it will be working in no time at all.

Comment: its the same problem as above in my edit.. i want to be able to disable one of the buttons with ids #nextbt or #endbt using jquery depending on the if statement

Comment: I will do it in JavaScript, not jQuery.

Comment: where are you setting $type?

Comment: You set $type in your SQL code based on whether you want next or end